# Calling a Method on the FormClosed Event?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, user-controls

I have a UserControl with a ComboBox and a Button which opens up a Form on top of the UserControl. In this Form you Add/Edit/Delete items from the UserContols' ComboBox.

I also have a Method `RefreshData()` in the UserControl's class that refreshes the data (By rebuilding the datatable) in the ComboBox when you press other controls within the UserControl. -Both this Method, and the ComboBox have Public access modifiers. (But not Static - which is possibly the issue?!)

`RefreshData()` works fine when it is being called from within its own class (ie, when its being called by controls on the same UserControl). However I also need to refresh the data in the UserControls' combobox when I `Close` the Form which edits the Data.

-The problem is that the `FormClosing` handler is calling `RefreshData()`, but it's not actually refreshing the data on the other form. -I have tried this in both `FormClose` and `FormClosing` event handlers.
(I know its being called because I can step into it whilst debugging)

This is my Code:

RefreshData() Method:

```
public void refreshdata()
    {
        SQLiteConnection sqlcon = new SQLiteConnection("data source =" + SqliteClass.dir + "\\SupportDash.sqlite");
        sqlcon.Open();
        SQLiteCommand getdataDesc = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT ID, URLDescription, URLAddress, Type from URLS", sqlcon);
        SQLiteDataReader reader;

        reader = getdataDesc.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("URLDescription", typeof(string));
        dt.Load(reader);
        //Description ComboBox
        Report.ValueMember = "ID";
        Report.DisplayMember = "URLDescription";
        Report.SelectedValue = "ID";
        Report.DataSource = dt;
        sqlcon.Close(); 
    }
```

Calling it from the other Form:

```
this.FormClosed += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(AddReport_Close);

void AddReport_FormClosing(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        RRunner r = new RRunner();
        r.refreshdata();
    }
```

As well as trying both event handlers, I've also tried: (All of these are in the Form_Closing event handler)

- `r.Invalidate(); Application.DoEvents();`
- `r.Refresh();`

I've also tried clearing all controls off the UserControl, then re-drawing them:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls)
        {
            splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Clear();
            break;
        }
        RRunner rrunner = new RRunner();
        splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(rrunner);
```

Since none of these work, I believe my issue lies in the way I'm setting the EventHandlers for the `FormClosed' Event, however I just cannot see were I am going wrong?

Comment: What is `RRunner`? is it the user control?

Comment: RRunner is the `UserControl. AddReport is the `Form`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating new user control `RRunner` in `FormClosing` event and calling `refreshdata`. Obviously it's not going to work. You need to refresh the existing `RRunner`. If it was added to the form then following code should work.

```
void AddReport_FormClosing(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    RRunner r = this.Controls
                    .OfType<RRunner>()
                    .First();
    r.refreshdata();
}
```

Comment: The Form is on top of the UserControl, eg) MainForm holds UserControl > Another Form opens up on top of the main form? -So this wouldn't work? :/

Comment: So instead of `this` keyword you just need `anotherFormInstance.Controls.OfType<RRunner>().First();`

Answer (score -2):

The correct way of doing this is to include your cleanup code in a method that is being called in your `FormClosing` event handler (nothing ugly in that, in my opinion). Calling Application.Exit or closing the application the old-fashioned way then results in this event being generated. Which triggers the cleanup method.

```
private void Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}

private void FormClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Cleanup();
}

private void Cleanup()
{
    // do cleanup here
}
```